# Skyrim PC respec via console

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I've misplaced a perk, can I get it back?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35121/ive-misplaced-a-perk-can-i-get-it-back)

I built my character without really realizing the eventual limitations to the perk system and am scattered all over the place.  Has anyone figured out to re-distribute perks into appropriate areas using the console or mod?  Also, it would be helpful to redistribute my "Health/Stamina/Mana" balance to better fit my characters current direction.