# Resetting Perk points?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I've misplaced a perk, can I get it back?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35121/ive-misplaced-a-perk-can-i-get-it-back)

Is there a way to reset perk points, say if you accidentally set one or when you reach level 50 and you want to clear your points in smithing to put them in alchemy?

Answers for all platforms would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35121/6914